# bug on result of success function is "null" in Jquery ajax

Tags: jquery

When result of success function is "null", the message still display "have value".

Can anyone help me, many thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "getData.php",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.length == 0) {
                    $("#rlt").append("no value");
                } else {
                    $("#rlt").append("have value");
                }
            },
            dataType: "json"
        });
    }, 2000);
});

<p id="rlt"></p>
```

Comment: did you try adding in a console.log(result.length) before you if to see what the result length really is? If you're not familiar with console.log you will see the output in Chrome's inspector console or if using Firefox you will see it in Firebug's console.

Comment: also, if you could post an example of the results from your request, it might be helpful as well. We don't have access to "getData.php" so we really can't test that for you.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the value `null`, you're probably sending the string `"null"`, which will not have a zero length:

Test for the string itself.

```
if (result === "null") {
    $("#rlt").append("no value");
} else {
    $("#rlt").append("have value");
}
```

If you're anticipating an actual `null` value in the response, then you wouldn't want to use `.length`, because you'll get a `TypeError`.

---

By the way, I don't think a standalone `"null"` or `null` is valid JSON, but the native parsers don't seem to mind it.